# spring portlet mvc: keep parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

In my first render function I add a an object to my model, and in my JSP I display it using el `${user.firstname}`. However when I submit my jsp the handling function(actionmapping) and retrieve the object from my model it is null. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent this?

Short version of the Jsp:

```
<form action="x">
name: ${user.firstname}
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the value from the form, so for that reason it is always null. You have to include it in an input element (hidden if you don't wan't it to be editable, or in a text one if you need the user can change the value).

The form will only send the values that are in the html form tags.

For example:

```
<form action="x">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="${user.firstname}"/>
    name: ${user.firstname}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: since you mentioned spring, you should use the custom tags for form and input. see this example http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/form_processing)

Comment: @Belun It's not compulsory, though using spring tags has some advantages. But the problem is not due to use html form tags instead of spring tags.

Comment: Forgot the tags, made an update post since the question changes due to not using the spring form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385395/spring-portlet-mvc-model-attribute-is-null-despite-being-modelattribute