# spring portlet mvc: model attribute is null despite being modelAttribute?

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

In my rendermapping I put a User object in my model`(model.addAttribute)`.
In the coupled JSP I do:

```
<form:form action="x" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
Username: ${user.username}
Age: ${age}
This information is correct: <input type="checkbox" id="correctInformation"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

However in the method mathing x when I retrieve the user object using an `@ModelAttribute` tag the user object is a new instance instead of the one used in the form (the username is empty etc).

Does anyone know why this happens and the solution?

edit:
I can use `<input type:hidden path="username"/>` and it works but that isn't really that clean... Is there a better solution?

Comment: Same question as this one (also asked by yourself) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381478/spring-portlet-mvc-keep-parameters/4382508#4382508

Comment: Not the same question, that was just a basic HTML form. This is a Spring form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the same as the other question. You are not sending the information in the form unless you add a form tag for the fields. So the usual way to go is to add a hidden field to send this information like this:

with spring tags:

```
<form:hidden path="username" />
```

or just with a form tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value=" ${user.username}" />
```